# How to connect to Presto JDBC in PySpark?

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, presto

I want to connect to Presto server using JDBC in PySpark. I followed a [tutorial](https://blog.knoldus.com/connecting-presto-server-using-jdbc/) which is written in Java. I am trying to do the same in my Python3 code but getting an error:

`: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver`

I have tried to execute the following code:

```
jdbcDF = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:presto://my_machine_ip:8080/hive/default") \
    .option("user", "airflow") \
    .option("dbtable", "may30_1") \
    .load()
```

It should be noted that I am using Spark on EMR and so, `spark` is already provided to me.

The code from the aforementioned tutorial is:

```
final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoDriver";
    final String DB_URL = "jdbc:presto://localhost:9000/catalogName/schemaName";
    //  Database credentials
    final String USER = "username";
    final String PASS = "password";
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    try {
      //Register JDBC driver
      Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
```

Kindly notice the `JDBC_DRIVER` in the above code, I have not been able to deduce the corresponding assignment in Python3 *i.e.* in PySpark.

Nor have I added any dependency in any configuration whatsoever.

I expect to successfully connect to my presto. Right now, I am getting the following error, complete stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 172, in load
    return self._df(self._jreader.load())
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o90.load.
: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:315)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions$$anonfun$6.apply(JDBCOptions.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions$$anonfun$6.apply(JDBCOptions.scala:105)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:318)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:167)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to perform the following steps for connecting presto to pyspark.

1. Download [Presto JDBC driver jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/facebook/presto/presto-jdbc/0.221/presto-jdbc-0.221.jar) from [official website](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/current/installation/jdbc.html) and put it into spark master node.
2. Start pyspark shell with following params:

```
bin/pyspark --driver-class-path com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoDriver --jars /path/to/presto/jdbc/driver/jar/file
```

3. Try to connect to presto using spark

```
jdbcDF = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("driver", "com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoDriver") \  <-- presto driver class
    .option("url", "jdbc:presto://<machine_ip>:8080/hive/default") \
    .option("user", "airflow") \
    .option("dbtable", "may30_1") \
    .load()
```