# Unable to perform any function over dataframe due to socket connection timed out while using pyspark with Presto on EMR

Tags: python, apache-spark, jdbc, pyspark, presto

I want to connect my spark deployed on EMR to Presto which uses Hive as meta-store and S3 as data storage. Earlier, I was unable to even execute the dataframe's loading from spark.read function available in pyspark but then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56806009/10834788) answer solved that for me. However, due to lazy execution, it was revealed that while fetching the count, the query is getting failed with an error: Socket connection timed out.

It should be noted that the same query `select * from may30_1` on the same instance using Presto's CLI, I was able to get the results. So, it is not the case of any network connectivity in between the servers.

This is the code which is used to fetch the dataframe:

```
jdbcDF = spark_session.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("driver", "com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoDriver") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:presto://my_presto_ip:8080/hive/default") \
    .option("user", "my_user") \
    .option("dbtable", "may30_1") \
    .load()
```

Lines working are:

```
>>> jdbcDF.head
<bound method DataFrame.head of DataFrame[id: int, name: string, alignment: string, gender: string, eyecolor: string, race: string, haircolor: string, publisher: string, skincolor: string, height: int, weight: int, _athena_row_number_: bigint, _athena_timestamp_: timestamp, _athena_commit_id_: string]>
```

Now, the same `head` if given an argument, say 2, won't work as it needs data.

```
>>> jdbcDF.head(3)
```

[Here](https://pastebin.com/i0MzCXeN) you will get the full traceback.

Any query that would bring the data is throwing errors.