# Is there any way I can get awsglue libs in s3?

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, aws-glue

I am running a lot of glue jobs having the same code, so I thought I would move the code in s3 bucket and calling it common_code.py and just call it from the glue jobs. But I am having an issue while running it. The line I am getting an error is

```
df = spark.read \
            .format("JDBC") \
            .option("url", postgresURL) \
            .option("driver", postgresDriver) \
            .option("header", "true") \
            .option("query", "select max(job_id) as job_id from public.job_execution_detail") \
            .option("user", user) \
            .option("password", password) \
            .load()
```

Error says -

```
An error occurred while calling o88.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.DriverRegistry$.register(DriverRegistry.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions$$anonfun$5.apply(JDBCOptions.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions$$anonfun$5.apply(JDBCOptions.scala:99)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:318)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:167)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I think the code can't import awsglue libs or pyspark libs. This is just my thinking, but any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think it's related to your common_code.py as I've done something similiar.  Maybe an incorrect Driver name?

Comment: Think you need to wrap the query with an alias and submit the query. Can you try. Please refer to this:  https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67540906/why-is-dbtable-query-required-in-spark-jdbc

Comment: @BobHaffner I don't think this is about driver name because I am using the same code from the glue jobs which was tested, so the driver name is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

It was not related to my common_code.py, I actually messed up while connecting to the DB. I had passed the wrong arguments and learned that painfully.